# connection refused - connecting Neo4j/ES docker containers with graphaware

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, neo4j, docker-compose, graphaware

I am trying to connect Neo4j and ES docker containers using graphaware and I get what could be looking like a docker-to-docker connection issue.

```
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:9201 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

I can access both container data via http using a browser. At this stage I do not know where the issue is actually located since I am quite new with these technologies.

Versions I am using:

- neo4j: 3.5.3
- ElasticSearch 6.6.1
- graphaware-neo4j-to-elasticsearch-3.5.2.53.11.jar
- graphaware-server-community-all-3.5.2.jar
- graphaware-uuid-3.5.2.53.17.jar
- docker: 18.09.3

Here is my yml file.

```
version: '3.3'                                                                                                                                          
services:                                                                                                                                               
  neo4j:                                                                                                                                                
    restart: always                                                                                                                                     
    image: neo4j:3.5.3                                                                                                                                  
    container_name: neo4j                                                                                                                               
    environment:                                                                                                                                        
      - NEO4J_AUTH=none                                                                                                                                 
      - NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT=yes                                                                                                              
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_http_listen__address=:7474                                                                                                 
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_https_listen__address=:6477                                                                                                
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_bolt_listen__address=:7687                                                                                                 
      - NEO4J_dbms_memory_heap_initialSize=16G                                                                                                          
      - NEO4J_dbms_memory_heap_maxSize=16G                                                                                                              
    volumes:                                                                                                                                            
      - /home/leag/drive53/neo4j/data:/data                                                                                                             
      - ./neo4j/conf:/conf                                                                                                                              
      - ./neo4j/plugins:/plugins                                                                                                                        
      - /home/leag/drive53/imports:/import                                                                                                              
    ports:                                                                                                                                              
      - 7474:7474                                                                                                                                       
      - 7687:7687                                                                                                                                       
    networks:                                                                                                                                           
      - neo-ela                                                                                                                                         
  elastic:                                                                                                                                              
    build: .                                                                                                                                            
    container_name: elastic_container                                                                                                                   
    volumes:                                                                                                                                            
      - ./elasticsearch/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data                                                                                              
      - ./elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml                                                             
    environment:                                                                                                                                        
      - neo4j="http://neo4j"                                                                                                                            
    ports:                                                                                                                                              
      - 9201:9201                                                                                                                                       
    networks:                                                                                                                                           
      - neo-ela                                                                                                                                         
networks:                                                                                                                                               
  neo-ela:                                                                                                                                              
    driver: bridge
```

The neo4j.conf file:

```
# This setting should only be set once for registering the framework and all the used submodules
dbms.unmanaged_extension_classes=com.graphaware.server=/graphaware

com.graphaware.runtime.enabled=true

#UIDM becomes the module ID:
com.graphaware.module.UIDM.1=com.graphaware.module.uuid.UuidBootstrapper

#optional, default is "uuid". (only if using the UUID module)
com.graphaware.module.UIDM.uuidProperty=uuid

#optional, default is all nodes:
#com.graphaware.module.UIDM.node=hasLabel('Label1') || hasLabel('Label2')

#optional, default is uuidIndex
com.graphaware.module.UIDM.uuidIndex=uuidIndex

#prevent the whole db to be assigned a new uuid if the uuid module is settle up together with neo4j2es
com.graphaware.module.UIDM.initializeUntil=0

#ES becomes the module ID:
com.graphaware.module.ES.2=com.graphaware.module.es.ElasticSearchModuleBootstrapper

#URI of Elasticsearch; elastic works as well
com.graphaware.module.ES.uri=127.0.0.1

#Port of Elasticsearch
com.graphaware.module.ES.port=9201

#optional, protocol of Elasticsearch connection, defaults to http
com.graphaware.module.ES.protocol=http

#optional, Elasticsearch index name, default is neo4j-index
com.graphaware.module.ES.index=neo4j-index

#optional, node property key of a propery that is used as unique identifier of the node. Must be the same as com.graphaware.module.UIDM.uuidProperty (only if using UUID module), defaults to uuid
#use "ID()" to use native Neo4j IDs as Elasticsearch IDs (not recommended)
com.graphaware.module.ES.keyProperty=uuid

#optional, whether to retry if a replication fails, defaults to false
com.graphaware.module.ES.retryOnError=false

#optional, size of the in-memory queue that queues up operations to be synchronised to Elasticsearch, defaults to 10000
com.graphaware.module.ES.queueSize=10000

#optional, size of the batch size to use during re-initialization, defaults to 1000
com.graphaware.module.ES.reindexBatchSize=2000

#optional, specify which nodes to index in Elasticsearch, defaults to all nodes
#com.graphaware.module.ES.node=hasLabel('Label1')

#optional, specify which node properties to index in Elasticsearch, defaults to all properties
#com.graphaware.module.ES.node.property=key != 'age'

#optional, specify whether to send updates to Elasticsearch in bulk, defaults to true (highly recommended)
com.graphaware.module.ES.bulk=true

#optional, read explanation below, defaults to 0
com.graphaware.module.ES.initializeUntil=0
```

and elasticsearch.yml

```
network.publish_host: 127.0.0.1
network.host: 127.0.0.1
transport.tcp.port: 9300
http.port: 9201
http.host: 127.0.0.1
http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
http.cors.allow-methods: OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
http.cors.allow-headers: "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Content-Length, X-User"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, most likely, is that your neo4j is trying to connect to an elasticsearch running on the same machine as neo4j is

```
#URI of Elasticsearch; elastic works as well
com.graphaware.module.ES.uri=127.0.0.1

#Port of Elasticsearch
com.graphaware.module.ES.port=9201
```

Elasticsearch is not running on the same machine and you should avoid using 127.0.0.1 on your config files, try and swap the localhost address to the local dns address for ES, as such

```
#URI of Elasticsearch; elastic works as well
com.graphaware.module.ES.uri=elastic

#Port of Elasticsearch
com.graphaware.module.ES.port=9201
```

Comment: I would suggest also ( by knowing the use case of the question ), that neo4j depends_on the elastic running first, so the replication can happen on startup if needed.

Comment: I tried both suggestions and I still have the same problem.

Comment: is the org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException the same or did it change to "org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to elastic:9201 ..."?

Comment: Yes, it is now "org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to elastic:9201 [elastic/172.24.0.2] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)"

Comment: Try and change the network.host configuration in elasticsearch.yml to 0.0.0.0

Comment: Update: network.host was to 0.0.0.0 (sry, I did not update the files). I added     a healthcheck: test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://172.24.0.2:9200/"] with 5 retries. The error appeared only once. I was able to curl the address from the neo4j container as well.